# jQuery(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click()

Tags: jquery

I want to trigger click on specific points inside the iframe. can anyone please help me.

```
 jQuery(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click()
```

the above like is working fine without iframe.

Regards,

Comment: Is the contents of your iframe on the same domain as the containing site?

Comment: I have 2 scenarios:

1. contents are on the same domain.
2. contents are on the different domain, but this different domain is also owned by me.

Comment: Maybe try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8811344/1414562